# Does ReactJS Support Composed Components With Transitive Version Conflicts?

Tags: reactjs, build, npm, components, browserify

I'm wondering whether I can build apps with ReactJS and browserify using components that may have child component dependencies with different versions?

For example suppose component's A and B are used.  Component A depends on component C:1.0.2 and component B depends on Component C:2.0.5.

Would a react / browserify build run into issues with this?

The reason I'm curious is that the Polymer registry does not support transitive dependencies that have version conflicts:
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/326

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a test case for it but, I would assume that its possible. I would watch out for variable overrides when bundling or importing.

```
// Component A
import C as C from "/path/to/module";

//Component B
import C as C-2 from "/path/to/module.2";
```

Comment: Also investigating the same question for Ember: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809708/does-emberjs-support-composed-components-with-transitive-version-conflicts