# Does EmberJS Support Composed Components With Transitive Version Conflicts?

Tags: ember.js, build, dependencies, runtime

I'm wondering whether I can build apps with EmberJS and browserify using components that may have child component dependencies with different versions?

For example suppose component's A and B are used. Component A depends on component C:1.0.4 and component B depends on Component C:2.0.6.

The reason I'm curious is that the Polymer registry does not support transitive dependencies that have version conflicts: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/326

Would a emberjs / browserify builds run into similar issues?

TIA, Ole

Comment: As far as I know this is a problem shared by most front-end code, due to the browser environment where the code will be run. That's why some libraries make a "no conflct" mode so they don't get overridden, and why `bower` dependencies are flat.

Comment: I have also asked the same question for React: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808349/does-reactjs-support-composed-components-with-transitive-version-conflicts